# Get train/test data after using model.fit() with validation_split

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, scikit-learn, data-science

I am training and fitting a keras model using validation split:

```
self.model = Sequential()
self.model.add(LSTM(hidden_units, input_shape=(1, n_features), dropout=drp))       
self.model.add(Dense(n_classes, activation='sigmoid'))
self.model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
self.model.build(X_train.shape)

self.history = self.model.fit(X, y.values, epochs=epochs, batch_size=32, validation_split=0.33, shuffle=True,  callbacks=cb_list)
```

After fitting, I want to access the test set that was used.
How can I do this?

Comment: You should provide more information. What framework are you using? The labels say scikit-learn, but the method signature you show makes me think you are using keras or some other deep learning framework.

Comment: @xibalba1 pls see my edit

Comment: You are not using test in your model above. Also I think you mean to write `self.model.fit(X, y.values, epochs=epochs, batch_size=32, validation_split=0.33, shuffle=True,  callbacks=cb_list)` where `X = X_train` and `y.values = y_train`.

Comment: @Philip Yes, and this split X,y to 0.66 / 0.33 right? So how do I access the validation set?

Comment: As far as I can tell from the [documentation](https://keras.io/visualization/#training-history-visualization), you can access history.history['acc'], history.history['val_acc'], history.history['loss'], history.history['val_loss']. However, I have not seen any mention on the test set. However, you could split into test and training prior to this operation

Answer (score 2):

As per the FAQ in the [documentation](https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/), the `validation_split` attribute makes the last % of samples to be your validation data.

In your case, you set the value of `validation_split` to be 0.33. This means that the last 33% of the samples in X get used as validation data.

So, you can just directly slice off the last 33% of `X` and use it.